# Changing isVisible property of Xamarin Forms XAML buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to dynamically show/hide button inside Xamarin Forms ContentPage.
I have two buttons in my XAML code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <Button x:Name="start_btn" Clicked="startPanic">
        <Button.Text>START</Button.Text>
    </Button>

    <Button x:Name="stop_btn" IsVisible="false">
        <Button.Text>STOP</Button.Text>
    </Button>

</StackLayout>
```

Corresponding C# code:

```
public partial class PanicPage : ContentPage
{
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;

    public PanicPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        startBtn = this.FindByName<Button> ("start_btn");
        stopBtn = this.FindByName<Button> ("stop_btn");
    }

    private void startPanic(object sender, EventArgs args){
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            startBtn.IsVisible = false;
            stopBtn.IsVisible = true; //  DOESN'T WORK, button still will be hidden
        });
    }
}
```

When I set isVisible property in XAML, it doesn't react for any property change in event method (startPanic). How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread usage? Not sure why you are using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your code in xmal file and write properties for start and stop button

```
<Button x:Name="start_btn" Clicked="startPanic" IsVisible="{Binding IsStartVisible}">
    <Button.Text>START</Button.Text>
</Button>

<Button x:Name="stop_btn" IsVisible="{Binding IsStopVisible}">
    <Button.Text>STOP</Button.Text>
</Button>
```

In ViewModel write following property and similar for start button and set IsStopVisible =true/false based on your logic

```
   private bool _isStopVisible;

    public bool IsStopVisible{
        get {
            return _isStopVisible;
        }
        set {
            _isStopVisible= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged ("IsStopVisible");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm late but I was searching this too without success. This may be useful for someone.

```
objectView.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, false); // the view is GONE, not invisible
objectView.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine. I copied your code and cleaned it up a bit, it shows the STOP button, then I

A few remarks:

- use the short property where possible `<Button Text="X"/>`, it's
  easier to read
- when you add a XAML page the IDE adds a .xaml.cs file next to it and generates another .g.cs that you don't see. The .g.cs file
  contains generated code that finds all the x:Name'd elements and
  defines placeholders for them, no need to find them by name yourself
- all UI-initiated events are executed on the UI thread, no need to do that explicitly

Here's the XAML, same as yours just tighter and added Margin so the button is visible

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20">
  <Button x:Name="start_btn" Clicked="startPanic" Text="START" />
  <Button x:Name="stop_btn" Text="STOP" IsVisible="false" />
</StackLayout>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{   
    public TestPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void startPanic(object sender, EventArgs args){
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            start_btn.IsVisible = false;
            stop_btn.IsVisible = true;  
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tested your changes, but it didn't help in my case. What I've noticed,. that stop button shows for a short (half of second) moment and then desapears. What do you think about that?

Comment: I suggest you zip up your entire project and share it here via, say, dropbox. I'd also suggest resetting the simulator and running the code on hardware to make sure it isn't some fluke

Comment: When I'm doing that, I the error message `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "isVisible": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property`. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Richh94 Possibly because you're using "isVisible" instead of "IsVisible" (notice the capitalized first letter)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Visibility property of view.

for example if u want to make your button invisible you can do

```
if(condition)

    {

    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible;

    }

    else

    {

    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible;

    }
```

Comment: add some explanation