# Xamarin Forms ListView hide blank rows in cell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML for a custom cell in a ListView (boiled down to a simple example).

```
<ListView x:Name="___drives" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Address}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Scheduled}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the code-behind, I am binding an ObervableCollection of Drive objects to the ListView.  The Drive object is defined below.  It extends a ModelBase which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (details for that not shown, but are boilerplate).

```
public class Drive : ModelBase
{
    private string _address;
    private string _scheduled;

    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { if (_address != value) { _address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); } }
    }
    public string Scheduled
    {
        get { return _scheduled; }
        set { if (_scheduled != value) { _scheduled = value; OnPropertyChanged("Scheduled"); } }
    }
}
```

Sometimes Scheduled is null.  Is there a way to have the ViewCell not display a blank line for the Scheduled property when the value is null?

The image below is what results when there is no value for Scheduled (contains more fields, but you get the idea).  I drew in the red boxes to show the blank lines.  I want to have the DistanceToMe move up and take the space of the blank line.

[image]

Comment: What would you want instead of a blank line? Couldn't you simply check if `value` is `null`, and if so, set `_scheduled` to something which is sensible in your specific case?

Comment: No I want the display to collapse so the blank line isn't shown.  I have updated the question to show what I need to accomplish.

Comment: You could probably use the IsVisible property on the Label if it is available. I know it is for buttons. If it is available you can have a boolean property on the ViewModel that is set to false when Schedualed is null. For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/33751434/6198927

Comment: You could combine both the Address and Scheduled, only needing one label.  **OR** as @EstebanVerbel mentioned, why not just hook up a binding for the label visibility, based on `Scheduled`'s value?

Comment: @Verbel, that worked, thanks!

Comment: @Verbel, you might post your comment as the answer, so you can get the credit!

Comment: @EstebanVerbel can you add your comment as the answer and I will accept?

Comment: @JohnLivermore just posted it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IsVisible property on the Label if it is available. You can have a boolean property on the ViewModel that is set to false when Schedualed is null. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823619/changing-isvisible-property-of-xamarin-forms-xaml-buttons/33751434#33751434)