# Hide button after it was clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to hide a button after it was clicked but I don't know how.

C#

```
private async void btn1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // hide button
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Button Clicked="btn1Clicked"/>
```

Comment: Use IsVisible property of the button. You can bind it to a boolean of your view model and set to it's value to False when the button is clicked. See this link for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823619/changing-isvisible-property-of-xamarin-forms-xaml-buttons

Comment: Be sure you're building a UI that still makes sense if you have buttons disappearing - it's quite often confusing for the user unless it's really obvious why an action is no longer available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
private async void btn1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    if(condition)
    {
        // hide the button
        btn.IsVisible = false;
        
        // or disable the button. 
        // As Caius Jard said, disappearing buttons sometimes cause confusion.
        btn.IsEnabled = false; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility'. 'ViewStates' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Now I've edited the solution, give it a try.

Comment: It's working perfect, I went with ".IsEnabled". Thank you :)

Comment: Is it possible to make it disabled even after app restart?

Comment: Well, if button is enabled by default, I guess you have to run some checks when the application starts and to disable it if it is the case. Like `if actionIsNotAvailable => disable button`.

Comment: How can I access the button outside this function?

Comment: Give it a name like this: `<Button x:Name="btn1" Clicked="btn1Clicked"/>`. Now you can access it as btn1

Comment: I somehow can't access it via x:Name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your button invisible you can do:

```
if (condition)
{
    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible;
}
else
{
    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible;
}
```

Or you can use [IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isvisible?view=xamarin-forms) property.

Comment: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility'. 'ViewStates' does not exist in the current context.